# python - send pdf as bytes in web services

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, pdf, flask

I use to build a web service that response with `application-json` mime type.
But now I want to response a PDF as bytes, so I assume that I have to change mime type.
I will use routing but I could use flask-restful too.

The following code show the structure but I don't know how covert pdf to bytes and then send it.

```
@app.route('/pdf/myfile')
def pdf():
  data = open("myfile.pdf", "rb").read()
  # make a reponse with those bytes
  return response
```

In the client side (`angular.js`) I will have this:

```
$http.get('/pdf/myfile', null, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
       .success(function (data) {
           var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
           var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
           window.open(fileURL);
        });
```

Comment: Well, you could either use [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory) or do something like encode the file handle in base64 and return the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`send_file`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file) or [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory):

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/pdf/myfile')
def pdf():
    return send_from_directory('/dir/of/pdf', 'my.pdf')
```

By default this will send the file inline and browsers will probably render the PDF itself. If you set `as_attachment=True` the file will be presented as an attachment, and the browser will throw up a "save as" dialog box.

`send_file` gives you more control over things such as mime types and caching. The defaults should work well.